# rxCrossTabs crashes on a character variable

Tags: rstudio, revolution-r

When I run this in Revolution R Enterprise, it totally crashes Rstudio on the last line:

```
require(RevoScaleR)
set.seed(1)
a = sample(c("happy", "sad", "other", NA), 100, replace = TRUE)
y = data.frame(a)
y$a = as.character(y$a)
rxCrossTabs(1 ~ a, data = y)
```

This seems buggy to me.  Shouldn't it at least throw a warning and return me the command prompt?

The quick fix above is to simply exclude the line `y$a = as.character(y$a)`, but I'd rather really understand what is going on.  I'm having the same sort of crash with `rxCrossTabs` when I try to run it on a `.xdf` file, and I wonder if it is a related issue.  I.e., perhaps somehow R is reading in a column of the file as character only instead of as factor, but I'm not sure how to investigate that directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `Revolution R` problem; it's an `Rstudio` problem.  If I run your code in `R` in a terminal session, it does not crash, but it does throw an error message that `Rstudio` should have relayed to you:

[image]

Evidently your challenge now is to figure out how to put the right variable type on each column of interest in your .xdf file.  Specifically, you need to have a `factor` variable to use the `rxCrossTabs` function.